# Snake in JavaScript: I can't get my snakes tail longer

Tags: javascript

I made a snake game that works almost completely. I have one snake head, and an array which contains the head and all of the tails. When the snake eats a food, the food moves location, but my tail isn't getting bigger when I eat the food. I don't have an IMMENSE understanding of arrays, perhaps I'm doing it wrong?

Here is the code:

```js
setSize(400, 400);

var background = new Rectangle(getWidth(), getHeight());
background.setPosition(0, 0);
background.setColor(Color.black);
add(background);

// ------------------------------------------------
var gameTime = 0;

var snakeX = (Randomizer.nextInt(0, 19)) * 20;
var snakeY = (Randomizer.nextInt(0, 19)) * 20;

var foodX;
var foodY;

var snakeFood = new Rectangle(20, 20);
snakeFood.setColor(Color.red);

var food_eaten = 0;

var snakeSpeed = 20;

var keyLeft = false;
var keyRight = false;
var keyUp = false;
var keyDown = false;

var snake_size = 10;

var snakeHead = new Rectangle(20, 20);
snakeHead.setColor(Color.green);

var snakes = [snakeHead];
// ------------------------------------------------


function start(){
    setup();
    keyDownMethod(checkKey);
    setTimer(counter, 250);
}


function counter(){
    gameTime += 0.25;
    updateSnake();
}


function setup(){
    foodX = (Randomizer.nextInt(0, 19)) * 20;
    foodY = (Randomizer.nextInt(0, 19)) * 20;
    
    
    snakeHead.setPosition(snakeX, snakeY);
    add(snakeHead);
    
    snakeFood.setPosition(foodX, foodY);
    add(snakeFood);
}


function checkKey(e){
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
        
        keyRight = false;
        keyUp = false;
        keyDown = false;
        
        keyLeft = true;
        
    }else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
        
        keyLeft = false;
        keyUp = false;
        keyDown = false;
        
        keyRight = true;
    
    }else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
        
        keyRight = false;
        keyLeft = false;
        keyDown = false;
        
        keyUp = true;
        
    }else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
        
        keyRight = false;
        keyLeft = false;
        keyUp = false;
        
        keyDown = true;
    }
}

function updateSnake(){
    
    if(foodX == snakeX && foodY == snakeY){
        eat();
    }
    
    
    var dirX = 0;
    var dirY = 0;
    
    if(keyLeft == true){
        dirX = -(snakeSpeed);
        dirY = 0;
        
    }else if(keyRight == true){
        dirX = snakeSpeed;
        dirY = 0;
        
    }else if(keyUp == true){
        dirY = -(snakeSpeed);
        dirX = 0;
        
    }else if(keyDown == true){
        dirY = snakeSpeed;
        dirX = 0;
    }
    
    
    
    // moving the snake head
    
    snakeHead.setPosition(snakeX + dirX, snakeY + dirY);
    
    snakeX += dirX;
    snakeY += dirY;
    
    // moving the snake body
    
    if(snakes.length > 1){
        for(var i = 0; i < snakes.length; i++){
            var curr_body = snakes[i];
            curr_body.setPosition(snakeX + dirX, snakeY + dirY);
        }
    }
   
}


function eat(){
    foodX = (Randomizer.nextInt(0, 19)) * 20;
    foodY = (Randomizer.nextInt(0, 19)) * 20;
    
    var tail = new Snake(snakeX, snakeY);
    
    snakeFood.setPosition(foodX, foodY);
}


function Snake(x, y){
    var snakeBody = new Rectangle(20, 20);
    
    if(keyLeft == true){
        snakeBody.setPosition(x + snake_size, y);
    }if(keyRight == true){
        snakeBody.setPosition(x - snake_size, y);
    }if(keyUp == true){
        snakeBody.setPosition(x, y + snake_size);
    }if(keyDown == true){
        snakeBody.setPosition(x, y - snake_size);
    }
    
    snakeBody.setColor(Color.green);
    snakes.push(snakeBody);
    add(snakeBody);
}
```

Comment: check out the updateSnake() and eat() to get a better idea.

Comment: Your code isn't running in the snippet, which means that you haven't posted your full code. Please post the entire program you're trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

In your eat() function, you assign a new Snake object to a var tail, but then do nothing with it. I think you need to add it to your snakes array (which I assume represents the entire snake?)